# JSON data through jQuery AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post

I've having issues with parsing JSON data from a php file through to JQuery.I've had quite a difficult time finding the most appropriate way of doing this and any help would be appreciated. It needs to be in a function

At the moment I've gotten to the point of:

```
$.ajax({

    url: "Scripts/Interactions.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i, grab){
        alert(grab.AgentFullName);

        })

    }

})
```

While this works, one issue is it presents a row 'Undefined' before the first row, no matter what column I suggest.

Here is a sample of my Json Output data. It's mostly just random Ipsum Lorem at this text, as I'm still in early stages of development. I've checked the data through various online json format checkers and it's come back as valid.

http://pastebin.com/KFKtiSD4

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> [
>    "results",
>    {
>       "InteractionID":"1",
>       "AgentFullName":"Peter Germein",
> ```

referring the beginning of your json, you probably want to put **"results":**, instead of **"results",**

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm going for. However how would I correct this in my php file. It uses json_ncode. That's probably not enough information, so you can find the contents of Interactions.php here:
[link]http://pastebin.com/3KjDG0sF

Comment: try this, in line 12 **$return_arr = array("results");**, change array("results") to array(). then at any line between line 33 and 37, put in **$temp_arr = array();$temp_arr["results"] = $return_arr;$return_arr = $temp_arr;** (the point is to set the json array under an array index or column called results)

Comment: Sir, you're a complete legend! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

The first element in your array is not an object, it's a string.  That's why you're getting undefined for the first element when you say `grab.AgentFullName`—the string "results" has no such property.

You could change

```
[
   "results",
   {
      "InteractionID":"1",
      "AgentFullName":"Peter Germein",
      "InteractTopics":"Behaviour, Attendance, Attitude, Performance, Closing",
      "InteractDiscussion":"Cras at nisl lorem, a lacin...",
      "InteractAction":"Morbi quis nunc in odio eg...",
      "InteractNotes":"Quisque et ante ut nis..."
   },
```

to

```
[
   {
      "InteractionID":"1",
      "AgentFullName":"Peter Germein",
      "InteractTopics":"Behaviour, Attendance, Attitude, Performance, Closing",
      "InteractDiscussion":"Cras at nisl lorem, a lacin...",
      "InteractAction":"Morbi quis nunc in odio eg...",
      "InteractNotes":"Quisque et ante ut nis..."
   },
```

Or, were you trying to do this:

```
{
   "results": [
   {
      "InteractionID":"1",
      "AgentFullName":"Peter Germein",
      "InteractTopics":"Behaviour, Attendance, Attitude, Performance, Closing",
      "InteractDiscussion":"Cras at nisl lorem, a lacin...",
      "InteractAction":"Morbi quis nunc in odio eg...",
      "InteractNotes":"Quisque et ante ut nis..."
   },  
   {
      "InteractionID":"2",
      "AgentFullName":"Peter Germein",
      "InteractTopics":"Behaviour, Attendance, Attitude, Performance, Closing",
      "InteractDiscussion":"....",
      "InteractAction":"Morbi quis nunc in ...",
      "InteractNotes":"Quisque et ante ut nisi ..."
   },
```

Which would be parsed like this:

```
$.each(data.results, function(i, grab){
   alert(grab.AgentFullName);

})
```

Comment: Thanks, the latter is what I'm going for. However how would I correct this in my php file. It uses json Encode. That's probably not enough information, so you can find the contents of Interactions.php here:
[link]http://pastebin.com/3KjDG0sF

Comment: @Poika - I'm not a PHP guy.  I would ask a new question on how to serialize your PHP data to get what you're looking for.